# Is it possible to load contracts in hardhat genesis block?

Tags: hardhat, testing, genesis

I am trying to test certain aspects of BSC chain. I need some system contracts, which I can't easily deploy to other addresses without breaking the whole existing system.

Is it possible to add contracts to the genesis block of a hardhat network, on a predefined address?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`hardhat_setCode`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat-setcode) debug method to set your contract runtime bytecode to any address.
Additionally, you could set or modify any state variables with [`hardhat_setStorageAt`](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setstorageat).